# Getting data with an array (or with another way)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a method that takes answer id's (specific for each answer) from a database answer table- getAnswerId()

But I want to change it.  I created answer0,answer1, answer2 columns in question database and want to take 0,1,2 as answerId . How can I identify it for  getAnswerId() ?

*Shortly;*

**name of columns :answer0,answer1,answer2**

**take "0,1,2" as "*answerId*" and put it in "*getAnswerId()*"**

Then I want to use it like :

> public int getAnswerId() {
>
> ```
>         return this.answerId;
> }
> ```

EDITED:

sqlhelper:

```
final String query = "SELECT " +
            "answer._id, answerlang.AnswerText, answer.Correct, " +
            "answersquestions.QuestionID" +
            " FROM answersquestions" +
            " INNER JOIN answerlang" +
            " ON answersquestions.AnswerID = answerlang.AnswerID" +
            " INNER JOIN answer" +
            " ON answerlang.AnswerID = answer._id" +
            " WHERE answersquestions.QuestionID IN ( " +
            allQuestionIds +
            " )  ORDER BY answersquestions.QuestionID ";
    this.cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (this.cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            for (final Question q : questions) {
                if (q.getQuestionId() == this.cursor.getInt(3)) {
                    q.addAnswer(new Answer(this.cursor.getInt(0),
                            this.cursor.getString(1),
                            (this.cursor.getInt(2) == 1 ? true : false)));
                }
            }
        } while (this.cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    this.cursor.close();
```

this.cursor.getInt(0)  takes answer._id (_ids from answer table)

I changed database structure and added answer0, answer 1, answer 2 to answerlang table.
so I need id for each answers in one table.
I thought take **QuestionID** and  **0** (or 1,2) (from answer0,1,2)
so **answerID = QuestionID+0** will be spesific for each answer

Problem is how interval **QuestionID+0** go to place, instead of **this.cursor.getString(0)**

// // // // \ \ \ \

**Sumamry of my question :**

```
 use **this.sample.getInt()** instead of this.cursor.getInt(0)
for example:
    
    this.sample.getInt() : will have interval 10,11,12 for question 1 (QuestionID=1, answer0=0 so answer0 id = 10, answer1 id = 11, answer2 id = 12  as spesific id )
    
     will have interval 20,21,22 for question 2 (QuestionID=2, answer0=0 so answer0 id = 20 ...... as spesific id )
```

Comment: May I suggest you structure the question better? I'm not too sure what you're asking.

Comment: you want to fetch values of columns?

Comment: Please ask a question clearly so that we can help you..

Comment: Edited question. I hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that when **questionId=1 and answerFromDB="answer1"** what you can do is fist pass the question id to method and then contact questionId and the integer from the answerID into a new string and parse it into an integer so the result would be **11** in this case.
if **questionId=1 and answerFromDB="answer2"** then answerid will be **12** etc..

```
public int getAnswerId( String questionId) {
//here questionId=0 or 1 or 2 etc in string format 
String newAnswerId=questionId+answerFromDB.substring(8) 
 return Integer.parseInt(newAnswerId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use

```
Integer.parseInt(answerFromDB.substring(8));
"answerid0".substring(8) = 0
"answerid1".substring(8) = 1
```

etc